# using random numbers to execute a specific array function on an array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, runtime

a PHP function is selected at runtime. A random number is generated from 1-5. For each random number a specific array function should be executed ie
`shuffle(), sort(), rsort(), array_pop() and array_reverse().

below is my code but its not right.

```
`$numArray = array(6, 98, 54, 13, 25, 70);

$numbers = mt_rand(1, 5);

if($numbers == 1){

    $next = array_pop($numArray);
echo $next;
}
elseif($numbers == 2){

$next = array_reverse($numArray);
echo implode($next);
}
elseif($numbers == 3){

$next = rsort($numArray);
echo ($next);
}
elseif($numbers == 4){

$next = sort($numArray);
echo ($next);
}
else{
$next = shuffle($numArray);
echo ($next);
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with it? Doesn't compile? Not doing what it should do? Working, but not looking good enough? ...or?

Comment: sorry, okay so i dont think its giving me the proper results ... for one the shuffle method returns 1 as a result

Comment: `shuffle` works on the array itself and only returns true or false ([manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php))

Comment: The same goes for `sort` and `rsort`

Comment: And  `implode` needs two parameters.

Comment: And `echo ($next);` won't do if `$next` is an array. If you don't know the behaviour of a function, or are not certain, always look it up in the manual.

Answer (score 0):

For array output you must use print_r or var_dump

Also

```
`$numArray = array(6, 98, 54, 13, 25, 70);
```

is a mistake and must be

```
$numArray = array(6, 98, 54, 13, 25, 70);
```